# AngularJS controller is not a function, got undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Hi I am brand new to angular.  I'm just trying to add some hardcoded data to a table, and I'm getting 2 errors when I try to do it.
1. Uncaught ReferenceError: LookUpCtrl is not defined
2. Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'lookup.controller' is not a function, got undefined

Here is my controller lookup.controller.js

```
(function () {

'use strict';

angular
    .module('crm.ma')
    .controller('LookUpCtrl', LookUpCtrl);

function LookupCtrl() {
    var vm = this;

    vm.results = [
        {
            accountId: 1,
            accountName: 'some name',
            address: '201 some st',
            city: 'Columbus',
            state: 'OH',
            zip: 'zip',
            phone: '999-999-9999',
            parentName: 'Parent 1',
            accountType: 'Type 1',
            accountStatus: 'Status 1',
            creditTerm: 'Term 1'
        },
        {
            accountId: 2,
            accountName: 'some name',
            address: '201 some st',
            city: 'Columbus',
            state: 'OH',
            zip: 'zip',
            phone: '999-999-9999',
            parentName: 'Parent 1',
            accountType: 'Type 1',
            accountStatus: 'Status 1',
            creditTerm: 'Term 1'
        }
    ];

}
}());
```

Here's my view lookup.html

```
<div>
<div>Lookup Results</div>
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td>Acc. ID</td>
            <td>Acc. Name</td>
            <td>Acc Address</td>
            <td>City</td>
            <td>Zip</td>
            <td>Phone</td>
            <td>Parent Name</td>
            <td>Account Type</td>
            <td>Account Status</td>
            <td>Credit Term</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="result in vm.results">
            <td>{{ result.accountId }}</td>
            <td>{{ result.accountName }}</td>
            <td>{{ result.address }}</td>
            <td>{{ result.city }}</td>
            <td>{{ result.state }}</td>
            <td>{{ reuslt.zip }}</td>
            <td>{{ result.phone }}</td>
            <td>{{ result.parentName }}</td>
            <td>{{ result.accountType }}</td>
            <td>{{ result.accountStatus }}</td>
            <td>{{ result.accountStatus }}</td>
            <td>{{ result.creditTerm }}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

if any further information is needed please let me know.  Thanks.

Comment: have you tried moving angular
    .module('crm.ma')
    .controller('LookUpCtrl', LookUpCtrl); after the  LookUpCtrl definition? This should fix one error but not the other. It's the first time i see a controller defined this way

Comment: Try declaring your function before calling angular.controller perhaps?

Comment: Its very unclear what you are asking...the code which you have added is not relating with what you are asking..

Comment: @CollinD That got rid of the error Uncaught ReferenceError: LookUpCtrl But I am still getting no data displayed in my table.  And I still get the error message Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'lookup.controller' is not a function, got undefined

Comment: @PankajParkar Why even respond?  What further information do you need?

Comment: @valepu Is there a better way to write it?  Can you show me some code.  I am brand new to this.

Comment: @hollyquinn I doubt somewhere in your code you are using `lookup.controller` as a variable.. that causing the second part breaks

Comment: no one spotted the typo? LookUpCtrl !== LookupCtrl

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a typo:

```
angular
    .module('crm.ma')
    .controller('LookUpCtrl', LookUpCtrl); //This should be LookupCtrl, as your function name is "LookupCtrl"

function LookupCtrl() {}; //Check the camelcase name.
```

So, the correct code would be:

```
angular
    .module('crm.ma')
    .controller('LookUpCtrl', LookupCtrl);
```

Comment: taxicala thank you so much.  I can't believe it was a stupid typo.  You are my hero.

Comment: No problem, glad to help! :) for the record, no one is safe from typos ;)

Answer (score 0):

You aren't calling the initialization properly. I don't know if it's possible to make a controller without $scope but i suggest you to use it. This is how to i usually initialize an angular controller. You can safely define the function earlier instead of passing it as argument like i did though

```
var app = angular.module('crm.ma', []).controller('LookUpCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope){   
$scope.results=[ 
        {    
            accountId: 1,
            accountName: 'some name',
            address: '201 some st',
            city: 'Columbus',
            state: 'OH',
            zip: 'zip',
            phone: '999-999-9999',
            parentName: 'Parent 1',
            accountType: 'Type 1',
            accountStatus: 'Status 1',
            creditTerm: 'Term 1'
        },
        {
            accountId: 2,
            accountName: 'some name',
            address: '201 some st',
            city: 'Columbus',
            state: 'OH',
            zip: 'zip',
            phone: '999-999-9999',
            parentName: 'Parent 1',
            accountType: 'Type 1',
            accountStatus: 'Status 1',
            creditTerm: 'Term 1'
        }
    ];
}]);
```

remember to use `<tr ng-repeat="result in results">` in your html